# How to configure Django application at http://SERVER-IP/ instead of http://SERVER-IP/Project using bitnami aws?

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, django, bitnami

I want to serve Django application at http://SERVER-IP/ OR a domain *(www.example.com)* instead of http://SERVER-IP/Project *(www.example.com/Project)* using [BITNAMI Django Stack(v4.2)](https://bitnami.com/stack/django).

I followed the documentation [here](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/infrastructure/django/#first_steps) for creating new application which is working perfect but I didn't find the way how to configure Django application at http://SERVER-IP/.

OS Details:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
ID=debian
```

I had tried:

1. Move application files form `~/apps/django/django_projects/PROJECT/` to `~/apps/django/django_projects/`
2. Updated all path in thses conf files:

   - httpd-prefix.conf
   - httpd-app.conf
   - PROJECT/wsgi.py
3. Restart the Apache server.

**But** unfortunately, still I'm getting the apache homepage at http://SERVER-IP/ instead of Django application homepage. One more thing Django application still accessible at http://SERVER-IP/Project successfully.

**Note:** I need both services is running `php` and `django`.

PHP demo app I've placed in `htdocs/demo/index.php` I want also this approachable form URL `http://SERVER-IP/hello/index.php`.

Someone, please guide me!!! How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to change the URL for your Django project to "/", you need to modify this file (supposing that the project you want to move to "/" is "Project"):

```
INSTALLDIR/apps/django/django_projects/Project/conf/httpd-app.conf
```

Inside the file, change these lines:

```
Alias /Project/static "INSTALLDIR/..."
WSGIScriptAlias /Project 'INSTALLDIR/...'
```

To this:

```
Alias /static "INSTALLDIR/..."
WSGIScriptAlias / 'INSTALLDIR/...'
```

And restart Apache after that:

```
sudo INSTALLDIR/ctlscript.sh restart
```

Please refer [Bitnami Django For AWS Cloud](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/components/django/#production://) And  [How can change the default URL](https://community.bitnami.com/t/how-can-change-the-default-url-example-com-xxx-to-access-my-application/55212/3)

Comment: Thanks it's works for python, But now how can i access the php app. URL like `SERVER-IP/hello/index.php` I've demo folder in htdoc.

Comment: As per community, can't run stack that includes PHP and Python at the same time. check this one - https://community.bitnami.com/t/php-and-python-at-the-same-time/43943/2

Comment: helpful for you - https://community.bitnami.com/t/how-do-i-add-python-to-the-bitnami-lamp-stack/40271

Answer (score 4):

You can use the bnconfig tool to move the app to root.

```
/opt/bitnami/apps/django/bnconfig --appurl /
```

You can find more information about the bnconfig tool here:

https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/components/bnconfig/